# How to return an array of 3 columns from a database by using loop

Tags: php, arrays

The problem is, I have a table with some content. The table name is `departments`. It has 3 columns `id`,`short_name`,`long_name`.

Now i am making a class which will return all the departments in an array but i can't go through that. I used `array_push()` to make array but can't get enough hint, any other ideas??

#### Code:

```
$con= $this->con;
$db_name= $this->db_name;
$sql="SELECT * FROM $db_name.departments";
$result= mysql_query($sql, $con); 
$data=array(); 
while($happen= mysql_fetch_object($result)) { 
   array_push($data,array([$happen->id],[$happen->short_name],[$happen->long_name])‌​); 
}
return $data;
```

Comment: code upto now is:$con=  $this->con;
        $db_name=  $this->db_name;
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `$db_name`.`departments`";
        $result=  mysql_query($sql, $con);
        $data=array();
        while($happen=  mysql_fetch_object($result))
        {
            array_push($data,array([$happen->id],[$happen->short_name],[$happen->long_name]));
            
        }return $data;

Comment: what kind of table? database?

Comment: ya database.. i have also tried to give my code there

Comment: Next time put your code in the question, not a comment.

Comment: ok, thanks, next time, ill remember

Comment: while($happen=  mysql_fetch_object($result))
        {
            array_push($data,array("id"=>$happen->id,"short_name"=>$happen->short_name,"long_name"=>$happen->long_name));
            
},
up to now, i have done this, can i turn this array into object or can i make an object at the begenning itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$con= $this->con; 
$db_name= $this->db_name; 

$sql="SELECT * FROM {$db_name}.departments"; 

$result= mysql_query($sql, $con); 

$data=array(); 

while ($happen= mysql_fetch_object($result)) 
{ 
    $data[$happen->id]['id']         = $happen->id;
    $data[$happen->id]['short_name'] = $happen->short_name;
    $data[$happen->id]['long_name']  = $happen->long_name;
}

return $data;
```

The above adds your data in the array based on the unique ID (using that as a key).

EDIT - restructured response after additional data was provided.

Comment: can we convert this result inro array?

Comment: The `$data` is an array with the `id` as a key and properties `id`, `short_name` and `long_name` for each element

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `mysql_fetch_object()` just use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

Also, I'd try and avoid using mysql_* if you can and just switch to using PDO immediately.

Comment: i dont know pdo nicely, i will switch to that after i learn that.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use mysqli_fetch_assoc().

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

It dumps your result set directly into an array like the one you are describing.  Also, mysql_query is deprecated and should not be used.  You need to look into the mysqli or pdo functions.